# Connect to Google Cloud SQL using .Net Framework

Tags: c#, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have found a articles on how to connect to Cloud SQL using .Net Core but nothing for .Net Framework.

I found this one but adding tcp: before the instance did not work
[How do I connect to Google Cloud SQL Server using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68107925/how-do-i-connect-to-google-cloud-sql-server-using-c)

I setup a Compute Engine using Windows 2016 Server with IIS installed. The web pages come up fine but they do not connect to the Cloud SQL. I am able to connect to the server through Management Studio using the sql proxy service so I know instance and database are correct.

Here is the connection string that I am using:

```
<add name="connectionString" connectionString="Data Source=<instance>;Initial Catalog=<database>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: What specifically is the error when you're connecting the Cloud SQL? How are you trying to connect to the Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 1):

With the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy running on the Compute Engine VM instance, trying using

```
Data Source=tcp:127.0.0.1,1433;
```

in the connection string for your web app.